# Values of Enum types

Tags: c#, enums

I'm just wondering why I get this output :

```
enum MyEnum
{
    a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3,
    d=3,
    f=d
}
Console.WriteLine(MyEnum.f.ToString());
```

**OUTPUT

c**

**But in Mono**
**OUTPUT**

**f**

***So why is the output c? not d? How does the compiler choose c? If I change the code like this:***

```
enum MyEnum
{
    a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3,
    d=3, 
    k=3
}
Console.WriteLine(MyEnum.k.ToString());
```

**OUTPUT**

**c**

 again!

*Another example*:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    a=3,
    b=3,
    c=3,      
    d=3,
    f=d,   
}
MessageBox.Show(MyEnum.f.ToString());
```

**OUTPUT**

**c**

Comment: very good question, i wonder myself as well. perhaps because it's first?

Comment: Just to be sure: you do know that you've assigned "c" the value of 3 also...?

Comment: i dont have any idea,maybe becouse of its first but i want to dig in deep

Comment: +1 good question, I'm waiting to know the motive.

Comment: Did you test it on Mono ? It sounds true behavior of compiler. In your first example, I got **f** instead of **c**

Comment: @minhcat_vo no i didnt test in mono, if its f its more weird :) in anyway are you sure its f in mono? i can edit my question again

Comment: Nope, I don't think so, we got value "f" that would be more semantic.

Comment: @minhcat_vo so i m editing this too?

Comment: It's up to you :). But the thing is you point the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From MSDN:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you
>   attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration
>   member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make
>   any assumptions about which name the method will return.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx#Y300

Comment: The apparent randomness in which enumeration name is selected is because `ToString()` for an enumeration without a `[Flags]` attribute uses a **binary search** to find the first enumeration name with the specified value efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The output is c because ToString resolves the index of the enum and prints out the representation at that index.  In the first example, d=3, and the third indexed enum value is c.  Similarly, when looking for the third index for k, it arrives at c before k, so that is again the output.

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate. This `enum MyEnum {a=1,b=2,c=3,d=2,f=d}` , according to your explanation, should print `b` and it prints `f`

Comment: Technically it doesn't really index like that.  It just so happens that the first name that the methods see that has the same value turns out to be `c`.

Comment: That's not how it works.. it just happened to be the case in this example. Try `a=3, b=3, c=7, d=3, f=d`. Prints out `f`. Set `c=2`, and it prints out `d`.